# Why doesn't my code work in ideone.com?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Admit {

    // the main method has minimal dialogue and just calls the other methods with the appropriate parameters.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        promptUser();
        System.out.println("Information for the first applicant:");
        double person1Score = getAllResults();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Information for the second applicant");
        double person2Score = getAllResults();
        System.out.println("First applicant's overall score  = " + person1Score);
        System.out.println("Second applicant's overall score = " + person2Score);
        compareScores (person1Score, person2Score);

    }

    // promptUser() introduces the program and what it's used for.
    public static void promptUser() {
        System.out.println("This program compares two applicants to");
        System.out.println("determine which one seems like the stronger");
        System.out.println("applicant. For each candidate I will need");
        System.out.println("either SAT or ACT scores plus a weighted GPA.");
        System.out.println();
    }

    // getAllResults() calculates the applicant's overall score to be compared,
    // depending on whether the user submitted SAT or ACT scores.
    public static double getAllResults() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\tDo you have 1) SAT scores, or 2) ACT scores? ");
        int testType = userInput.nextInt();
        // @var vinalScore is just storing an arbitrary value for now.
        double finalScore = 0;
        if (testType == 1) {
            System.out.print("\tSAT Math? ");
            int SATMath = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\tSAT Verbal? ");
            int SATVerbal = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\tActual GPA? ");
            double yourGPA = userInput.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("\tMax GPA? ");
            double maxGPA = userInput.nextDouble();
            double testScore = calculateSATScore(SATVerbal, SATMath);
            double finalGPA = calculateGPA(yourGPA, maxGPA);
            finalScore = calculateOverallScore(testScore, finalGPA);
        }
        else if (testType == 2) {
            System.out.print("\tACT English? ");
            int ACTEng = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\tACT Math? ");
            int ACTMath = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\tACT Reading? ");
            int ACTRead = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\tACT Science? ");
            int ACTSci = userInput.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\tActual GPA? ");
            double yourGPA = userInput.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("\tMax GPA? ");
            double maxGPA = userInput.nextDouble();
            double testScore = calculateACTScore(ACTEng, ACTMath, ACTRead, ACTSci);
            double finalGPA = calculateGPA(yourGPA, maxGPA); 
            finalScore = calculateOverallScore(testScore, finalGPA);
        }
        return finalScore;
    }

    // calculateSATScore() calculates the overall SAT score taken from getAllResults().
    public static double calculateSATScore(int verbal, int math) {
        double SATScore = (2 * verbal + math) / 24;
        return SATScore;
    }

    // calculateACTScore() calculates the overall ACT score taken from getAllResults().
    public static double calculateACTScore(int eng, int math, int read, int sci) {
        double ACTScore = ((2 * read) + eng + math + sci) / 1.8;
        return ACTScore;
    }

    // calculateGPA() calculates the final GPA taken from getAllResults().
    public static double calculateGPA(double uGPA, double mGPA) {
        double finalGPA = uGPA / mGPA * 100;
        return finalGPA;
    }

    // calculateOverallScore() computes the final scores to be compared, using the
    // overall test scores and the final GPA.
    public static double calculateOverallScore(double testScore, double GPA) {
        double overallScore = testScore + GPA;
        return overallScore;
    }

    // compareScores() compares the overall scores for each applicant and then prints out
    // which applicant appears to be the better choice.
    public static void compareScores (double person1, double person2) {
        if (person1 > person2) {
            System.out.println("The first applicant seems to be better.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The second applicant seems to be better.");
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error that says 'Main.java:11: error: class Admit is public, should be declared in a file named Admit.java
public class Admit {'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the example Java code: http://ideone.com/samples#sample_lang_10

Change "public class Admit {" to "public class Main {"

Your app probably won't work tho, as it looks like you use the

```
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
```

to receive keyboard input, and the ideone.com only accepts STDIN, which may not be supported by Scanner.

Case in point, when I run the modified code, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:838)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
at Main.getAllResults(Main.java:32)
at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: Yup, makes sense. Too bad I can't change the input to some other format that Scanner would recognize. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine. The error you quote is an issue with your file name not matching your class name. The file needs to be named Admit.java since your class is named Admit.